# How to insert Japanese character to ECC from Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I can see the Japanese text in the **Excel** cells. I've got the **VBA** code to update **ECC**. It does the **INSERT** in the **ECC**, but Japanese characters are simply represented as `????`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, is there any code to assign the japanese text to the variable, as it is.

Comment: Try using StrConv to store the Japanese string as Unicode.  When you want to display the string again, you could use the same function.  Check this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264628.aspx) or maybe this one [Japanese Link](http://officetanaka.net/excel/vba/function/strconv.htm)

Comment: Still having the same problem  cv = StrConv(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value, vbUnicode) i am using this code but it is saving same values instead of Japansese string.. Pl. help me

Comment: If i enter the values directly in the ECC table the char will be same. But while i am uploading the data excel the values will be storing as "????". Please do need full to solve issue.
        Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried retrieving the string using ´StrConv(myJapString, vbFromUnicode)´?

Comment: If you post the code you are using to read/retrieve the string maybe i could help further.  What is the ECC?

Comment: Thanks CaBieberach, headTextStr.Value(inCnt, "TEXT_LINE") = Sheet1.Range("L" & rwNum).Value, to update the internal table of SAP system i tried by using vbUnicode and vbFromUnicode, but still it is updating with ????? only.

Comment: I am not retriving any value, i am updating the excel sheet values to SAP system by using VBA code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24191/discussion-between-cabieberach-and-user1049518)

Comment: when i type in SAP it is showing the japansese char correctly
when i see in debug mode in VBA, it is showing ????
I believe the issue is in VBA only, may be it is not handling the different languages apart from English.

Comment: But while i see in debug mode in SAP, it is showing what i see in VBA debug window. same values like ???? only updating in SAP

Comment: maybe excel stores japanese char in EUC-JP.

Comment: how can we see the Japanese char in VBA editor

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, feels like it's been quite a time since the question was raised. 
But still I'd like to propose a solution:
Using `unicode` `encoding` to represent different language:
`Sheet1.Cells(2, 1) = ChrW(&H3091)`,
which is standing for character `ゑ`.

Answer (score 0):

You need MS Excel Japanese Language Pack to display Japanese characters.

If you are importing text into Excel, you need to set the following.
.TextFilePlatform = 850
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=141269